# Magento 1.9 custom cache issue

Tags: php, magento, caching, magento-1.9

I have an issue with Magento Custom Cache.
I have Observer method which launches by cron, i write value to the cache:

```
Mage::app()->saveCache($visitorsCount, 'cached_google_analytics_visitors_count', [], $twoDaysInSeconds);
```

Value is successfuly saved and i'm able to extract it from cache here. And files

> mage---4ae_CACHED_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_VISITORS_COUNT

and

> mage---internal-metadatas---4ae_CACHED_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_VISITORS_COUNT

are here two.

Now it's time to extract value from cache in my block, so i do this way:

```
$visitorsCount = Mage::app()->loadCache('cached_google_analytics_visitors_count');
```

But it returns me false. I've investigated that the reason is that there is no CACHED_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_VISITORS_COUNT in metadatasArray in Zend_Cache_Backend_File class, but the file of metadatas exists.
More then, metadatasArray has this value when i'm writting value to the cache.

Hope your help.
Regards, Nikolay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the reason of error:
cron was running from another user than web-server, so php-proccess didn't have permissions to read the file with metadatas. I've launched cron from www-data user and it works correctly now